# Passing multiple arguments in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

The simple script below does not work when, rather than passing a single file name, I want to pass multiple files through expansion characters like *

```
#!/bin/bash
fgrep -c '$$$$' $1
```

If I give the command `script.sh file.in` the script works. If I give the command `script.sh *.in` it doesn't.

Comment: `$1` is not set to `*.in`; it's set to the first item that `*.in` expands to.

Comment: @chepner which *might* be `*.in`, if no matching files exist. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"$@"` to pass multiple file names to fgrep. `$1` only passes the very first file name.

```
fgrep -c '$$$$' "$@"
```

Comment: @mimenico Note that `$1` is a subset of `$@`, referring to *exactly* the first argument; also, quoting is (usually) better than not quoting:therefore, `$@` is better than `$*`.